# Modify Sublime Text 2 whitespace representation?

Tags: sublime-text-2, whitespace

**Is there a way to modify the whitespace representation characters so I can change it from dots and dashes to something else?**

Because I currently have whitespace characters being drawn always, it looks like this. I don't need it turned off, just interested in changing how it's represented.

[image]

I like how TextMate shows invisible characters but I would be ok with just being able to change the spaces to show a blank space instead of a dot.

[image]

Comment: What do you want it changed to?

Comment: @Joshua I would like to change the spaces to show a blank space instead of a dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as far as I can tell there's no way to customize the display of whitespace characters - it's dots and dashes, or nothing.
You can suggest this feature at [Sublime Text's UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/) or, if you're feeling ambitious, make a plugin that mimics TextMate's behavior.

Comment: Anyone has any ideas on how to do that on a plugin? It's very, very specific, and a quick look at the docs revealed no mention of this whatsoever...

Answer (score -1):

This was answered on Stack Overview ([Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154014/5594))

To view whitespace the setting is:

> // Set to "none" to turn off drawing white space, "selection" to draw
>   only the // white space within the selection, and "all" to draw all
>   white space "draw_white_space": "selection",

You can see it if you go into Preferences->Settings Default. If you edit your user settings (Preferences->Settings - User) and add the line as per below, you should get what you want:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Slush & Poppies.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 10,
    "draw_white_space": "all"
}
```

Remember the settings are JSON so no trailing commas.

Comment: "I don't need it turned off, just interested in changing how it's represented."

Comment: This does not turn it off. It displays the spaces as DOTS and the tabs as DASHES. Did you actually try the settings. It worked just fine on my setup. I would be happy to provide screen captures. The original answer on Stack Overflow was accepted with 20+ upvotes.

Comment: He already has dots and dashes